# Consider P={0, 1/5, 3/10, 2/3, 3/5, 14/15, 1} Find the mesh of P.

Tags: calculus

My professor says that the answer is 1/3 but he never explained to us how he got that. Just hoping for some insight!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the maximum distance between any two consecutive numbers in that set. The mesh$P$ is just the length of the largest subinterval $[x_i-x_{i-1}]$ in your partition. So let $x_0=0$, $x_1=\frac{1}{5}$,.... and find the largest difference.

Answer (score 0):

The mesh is the length of the longest sub-interval, and that longest sub-interval is at $\{3/5, 14/15\}$ and their difference is $1/3$.

Comment: How do I know what the longest sub interval is?

Comment: you do the calculations unless it is obvious by inspection.